# How i can generate migrations with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, code-first

I want to generate my database by code firt approach with hibernate and java. I have success generating database but i miss out my migrations files. Have hibernate support to migrations like EntityFrameworkCore in .NEt, Eloquent in PHP or Sequelize in node?

This is my class that generate the database:

```java
public class CreateDataBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.configure();

      SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(conf);
      se.create(true,  true);  
    }
}
```

This is my schema:

```java
package Infra.HibernateConfiguration;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity 
public class Bank {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 

    @Column()
    private String code;

    @Column()
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).

> Both Flyway and Liquibase support all features that you need for
> professional database refactoring and versioning, so you will always
> know which version of the database schema you are dealing with and if
> it matches to the version of your software. Both tools are integrated
> with Maven or Gradle build scripts so that you can fully automate database refactoring.

Comment: Flyway does not support the generation of migrations: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2667. Additionally, setting this up with Liquibase is all but trivial.